# Exporting a tabular type object into a spreadsheet

Tags: r, tabular

I have data such as this:

```
require(tables)
varList <- 2:4
lapply(varList,function(x,df,byVar){ 
         tabular((Factor(df[[x]],paste(colnames(df)[x])) + 1) ~ ((Factor(df[[byVar]],paste(byVar)))*((n=1) + Percent("col"))),
             data= df) 
  },mtcars,"cyl")
```

I would like to export this data into a spreadsheet (right now, I am copy pasting it into excel).

I get this error when I tried exporting it into excel:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
cannot coerce class ‘"tabular"’ to a data.frame
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function for it in the `tables` package called `write.csv.tabular`, however in your example the tabular data inside of your `lapply` statement is converted to class `list`, so you're actually working with a list *of* tabular objects, which is a big different from working directly with tabular data.

```
class(data)
[1] "list"
```

The `list` contains 3 tabular objects, but it's still class `list`, which confuses the export functions.

I'll show how to write out `tabular` data directly and then proceed to work with the `list` of `tabular` objects.

Here's an example for tabular data created from the `iris` data set:

```
require(tables)

tabular_data <- tabular( (Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*
                                       (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean   + sd), data=iris )

write.csv.tabular(tabular_data, "tabular_data.csv")
```

Getting back to your original example, we'll need to use an Excel package in R like `xlsx` and convert the list item classes from `tabular` to something it can handle. Since `tabular` doesn't directly convert to `data.frame` we can use `data.frame.matrix` at the cost of having to do a little more work to recover your column headers.

First without worrying about column headers:

```
library(tables)
library(xlsx)

varList <- 2:4
data    <- lapply(varList,function(x,df,byVar){ 
  tabular((Factor(df[[x]],paste(colnames(df)[x])) + 1) ~ 
            ((Factor(df[[byVar]],paste(byVar)))*((n=1) + Percent("col"))),
          data= df) 
},mtcars,"cyl")

data <- lapply(data, as.data.frame.matrix) 

file <- paste("your_workbook.xlsx", sep = "")
write.xlsx(data[[1]], file, sheetName = "Sheet1") 
write.xlsx(data[[2]], file, sheetName = "Sheet2", append = TRUE)
write.xlsx(data[[3]], file, sheetName = "Sheet3", append = TRUE)
```

Now, in terms of the column headers let's look at one of your tabular list items and we'll see there's really no proper column names created in the first place:

```
varList <- 2:4
data    <- lapply(varList,function(x,df,byVar){ 
  tabular((Factor(df[[x]],paste(colnames(df)[x])) + 1) ~ 
            ((Factor(df[[byVar]],paste(byVar)))*((n=1) + Percent("col"))),
          data= df) 
},mtcars,"cyl")

     cyl                             
     4           6         8         
 cyl n   Percent n Percent n  Percent
 4   11  100     0   0      0   0    
 6    0    0     7 100      0   0    
 8    0    0     0   0     14 100    
 All 11  100     7 100     14 100
```

The `colLabels` attribute is a 3-row matrix whereas colnames can only be 1 element per column. So, we've got to workaround it.

The example in `?colLabels` simply subsets it to the values on 1 of those 3 rows, which leaves some columns without a header, i.e.

```
colLabels(data[[1]]) <- colLabels(data)[1,]
```

or

```
colLabels(data[[1]]) <- colLabels(data)[3,]
```

etc.

`paste` and `gsub` can be used to create a more complete set of column names, but there's no function to convert them to the special `colLabels` class, so you'd want to keep them as a string object then after converting your data to `data.frame.matrix`, `data.frame` or in the export to Excel set the strings as `colnames` for the corresponding sheets.

```
labels <- paste(colLabels(data[[1]])[1,],
                colLabels(data[[1]])[2,],
                colLabels(data[[1]])[3,])
labels <- gsub("NA ","",labels)
```

Comment: The exported data is not in a format that makes sense. I would like to see columns names etc.,

Comment: Sorry, my data is quite similar to the one I posted in my question, I guess it is a multi-list object, which I thought was also considered tabular.

Comment: Thanks! I get an error when I run:write.xlsx(data[[1]], file, sheetName = "Sheet1") .... Error in is.nan(tmp) : default method not implemented for type 'list'.

Comment: @NewBee When you use `write.xlsx` it should've already been converted from list to `data.frame.matrix` by `data <- lapply(data, as.data.frame.matrix)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write each table to its own csv to keep the structure of the tabular object:

```
lapply(1:length(a), function(x) write.csv.tabular(a[[x]], file = paste0("table_", x, ".csv")))
```